# Echoing Values from a multidimensional array

Tags: php

I'm able to pull information from a remote device, but the output is a pretty sizeable array and I'm having trouble formatting my syntax.  My array output looks like this;

```
array(420) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(99) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\CallsActive" ["Value"]=> int(3) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(102) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\CallsCompleted" ["Value"]=> int(172) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 1 Status" ["Value"]=> int(3) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [3]=> object(stdClass)#5 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 2 Status" ["Value"]=> int(3) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [4]=> object(stdClass)#6 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 3 Status" ["Value"]=> int(3) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [5]=> object(stdClass)#7 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 4 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [6]=> object(stdClass)#8 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 5 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [7]=> object(stdClass)#9 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 6 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [8]=> object(stdClass)#10 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 7 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [9]=> object(stdClass)#11 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 8 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [10]=> object(stdClass)#12 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 9 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [11]=> object(stdClass)#13 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 10 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [12]=> object(stdClass)#14 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 11 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [13]=> object(stdClass)#15 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 12 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [14]=> object(stdClass)#16 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 13 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [15]=> object(stdClass)#17 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 14 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [16]=> object(stdClass)#18 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 15 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [17]=> object(stdClass)#19 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 16 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [18]=> object(stdClass)#20 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 17 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [19]=> object(stdClass)#21 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 18 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [20]=> object(stdClass)#22 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 19 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [21]=> object(stdClass)#23 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 20 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [22]=> object(stdClass)#24 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 21 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [23]=> object(stdClass)#25 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 22 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [24]=> object(stdClass)#26 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 23 Status" ["Value"]=> int(2) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [25]=> object(stdClass)#27 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 24 Status" ["Value"]=> int(4) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [26]=> object(stdClass)#28 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 25 Status" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [27]=> object(stdClass)#29 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 26 Status" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [28]=> object(stdClass)#30 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 27 Status" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [29]=> object(stdClass)#31 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 28 Status" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [30]=> object(stdClass)#32 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 29 Status" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [31]=> object(stdClass)#33 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 30 Status" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [32]=> object(stdClass)#34 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\Channel 31 Status" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [33]=> object(stdClass)#35 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(105) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\DatalinkInService" ["Value"]=> int(1) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [34]=> object(stdClass)#36 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(108) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway01.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\OutboundBusyAttempts" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [35]=> object(stdClass)#37 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(99) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway02.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\CallsActive" ["Value"]=> int(0) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [36]=> object(stdClass)#38 (3) { ["Name"]=> string(102) "\\ip_address\Cisco MGCP PRI Device(gateway02.domain.com::S0_SU0_DS1-0)\CallsCompleted" ["Value"]=> int(109) ["CStatus"]=> int(1) } [37]=> object(stdClass)#39 (3)
```

I'm interested in getting the integer for CallsActive for gateway02.  So, I know that this syntax will allow me to print all objects "Name";

```
foreach($devices as $first)
        {
        $Name = $first->Name;
        echo $Name;
        }
```

How do you go about parsing this array?

Comment: If `$first->Name` is the name, then `$first->Value` is the value. To get the one value you are looking for, you will need to loop over each like you are doing and when the `$Name` is the one you expect, use that value.

Comment: that's exactly what I just did in my answer.  we think alike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($devices as $device){
       if((strpos($device->Name,'gateway02') !== false)&& (strpos($device->Name,'CallsActive') !== false)){
              echo $device->Name . " : " . $device->Value;
       } 
}
```

use strpos to check if the name contains those values, if so, do something with it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, RC and JK.  It was not the answer I was expecting, but it makes sense.

Comment: the data isn't very structured.  when you pull your array if you can provide filters, you could limit the returned array to only show records you care about.  That would be a better approach if possible.

Comment: I agree, it's a little confusing for me when I look at it because I'm not used to seeing it like this.  When I saw the solution using strpos, I kind of got the idea that this was how it was going to be for the situation.

Comment: yeah, it's also worth pointing out that the `strpos` matching would also print names including gateway022, or gateway0234 ect.. so if you know what that full value will be and can do a more specific test you should